# How long would it take to calculate a `n ** n`(n times n) with an `n` of 64165 digit in decimal?

Tags: python, c, algorithm

Assume this calculation was hold on a normal `I7`cpu.

Parts of this n looks like:`062818261573550755996975051396213990265395588957460690342970606032106870077208096704804861337086094604502447252509279335757453605836337900088980571550652843637152844978598425585659705979638641046274358312112553872770884438397651131234023085240167008580828612926148647820470126736393237752952205498922435592164336944705`

Things come on like this.

This afternoon suddenly a guess come to my mind. I was wondering if there exists a constant value `c` which makes `2**x == 3**(x/c)`

And I figured out an approximate value: `c = 1.5849116411760045`

I make an arbitrary `x = 213145` trying to examine how accurate this `c` value is.

I did `n = 3 ** (int(n/x)) - 2 ** n`, and be horrified that `n` is a decimal number with 64165 digits!

After that, I did a casual action: `n ** n`

I wait so long and the answer didn't come out.

And after a little ponder, I was astonished. I'm multiplying such a number with approximately `10**64165` times!

Then I'm wondering if it won't work out before the universe disappear!

But my colleague told me, CPU won't be foolishly trying to multiply it that much time. It will use some algorithm to shorten the time.

After a magic calculation, he told me, if my computer can do simple calculation `10**8` a second, in million years it can work it out.

Is that true?

Comment: If your question is how long would it take to calculate `64165**64165`, it took less than a sec on by pc with python 2.7.

Comment: Your value for `c` is log(3)/log(2), just as an aside. But I don't get what your exact question is, either.

Comment: Are you asking about `n**n` (exponentiation) or `n*n` (n times n)? If it's exponentiation, all of the computers on Earth put together don't have enough memory to store the result.

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD More like `n ** n`, where `n` has 64165 decimal places, so your result is the number of decimal places in the result. Compare that to the number of electrons in 99 kilograms of silicone or the universe.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the result will be a really big integer, so is not only the long pow operation, but also the allocation of the result, and both are heavy time and CPU consuming  operations.

Comment: How to approximately figure out the time consuming?

Comment: You have to know how your used Python version does this calculation and add your knowledge about the processor architecture, the way the RAM is connected with the processor and the operating system. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there exists a constant value c which makes `2**x == 3**(x/c)`

For a positive `x`, if

```
2**x == 3**(x/c)
```

then

```
log(2**x) == log(3**(x/c))

x * log(2) = (x/c) * log(3)
```

so

```
c = log(3)/log(2) ~ 1.5849625...
```

Comment: FWIW, rational approximations to this constant arise in the study of equally-tempered scales, eg [53 equal temperament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/53_equal_temperament). And of course, the usual way to find such approximations is to use a [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) algorithm... But I think we're all getting rather off-topic. :)